# How to delete a dynamoDb backup

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, backup

When I am trying to delete a backup on dynamoDb I am prompted with the following error message:

```
Invalid Request: User is not allowed to delete the system backup with arn 
arn:****. It will automatically expire on ***.
```

My account has however administration access . Is there a policy that does not allow back ups to be removed for a certain amount of time ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using AWS Backup to handle the backups of your DynamoDB tables. In that case you may want to review this document which will help you delete a backup plan: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/deleting-backups.html